# Possible combinations out of 256 items?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 256 different items. How many 128 items combinations are possible?

**edit:** When I say different combination, I treat 1 2 4 5 6 and 6 4 5 1 2 as ONE combination.

Comment: Does my question make sense?

Comment: If I understood correctly, $256 \choose 128$

Comment: I don't understand the symbol you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose $r$ distinct items from $n$ distinct items, then the number of the combinations is 
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}.$$

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what the ! are?

Comment: $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \cdots (n-1)\cdot n.$ For example, $5!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5.$

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: When I say different combination, I treat 1 2 4 5 6 and 6 4 5 1 2 as ONE combination.

Comment: Yes. If you have four items $ABCD$, then you want to treat $ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA$ as one combination, right?

Comment: yes, exactly that!

Comment: @Luka: So, the answer is $\binom{256}{128}$ for your question.

Comment: How much is that?

Comment: It is huge. see here. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=C%28256%2C128%29